# Compiler Warning: Modifier-style base constructor call without arguments

Tags: solidity

I get this compilation warning for the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract TestCalls {

    uint public lastMsgDataLength;
    uint public lastMsgValue;

    modifier setMsgFields {
        lastMsgDataLength = msg.data.length;
        lastMsgValue = msg.value;
        _;
    }

    constructor() setMsgFields public {
    }
}
```

I think that the compiler somehow misinterprets the modifier call as a base-constructor call.

Of course, there is no base constructor here, since the contract does not inherit anything.

How can I resolve this compilation warning?

P.S.: This code is taken directly from [Gnosis GitHub Repository](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/TestCalls.sol).

I have updated it from `^0.4.15` to `^0.4.24`, so perhaps this is the source of the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning will disappear if you add () to your modifier like this

```
  constructor() setMsgFields() public {
    }
```

Comment: When a modifier doesn't take any input arguments, I call it like this (i.e., without parenthesis). In fact, even in the contract that I asked this question about, the `setMsgFields` modifier is used like this (i.e., without parenthesis) in every other function. So this warning is restricted to the constructor alone???

Comment: yes only for constructor have a look at the reason behind https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/3853